# Looking for list of causes that result in "tunneling socket could not be established" on Node to do some methodic exception handling

Tags: node.js, http, exception

Writing some http-code using proxies.

Under load sometimes I'm getting:

- tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED
- tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ENETUNREACH

Where can I get a list of all error-codes that could be thrown as part of this? I don't want to fix the above two and get hit by a third, eleventh, etc. cause later down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are standard linux error codes. Those two are related to network. See the full list [here](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno). It comes handy to decipher the errors.